# OpenBSD sshd in rdomain

Tags: ssh, routing, openbsd

I am trying to set up a redundant CARP cluster with routing separation with rtables. All works fine, but how do i tell sshd to start **only** in rdomain 2?
I know i can start it manually with

```
# route -T4 exec /usr/sbin/sshd
```

But there seems no integration of rdomains in the sshd config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sshd_config(5)` shows:

```
 ListenAddress
         Specifies the local addresses sshd(8) should listen on.  The
         following forms may be used:

               ListenAddress hostname|address [rdomain domain]
               ListenAddress hostname:port [rdomain domain]
               ListenAddress IPv4_address:port [rdomain domain]
               ListenAddress [hostname|address]:port [rdomain domain]

         The optional rdomain qualifier requests sshd(8) listen in an
         explicit routing domain.  If port is not specified, sshd will
         listen on the address and all Port options specified.  The
         default is to listen on all local addresses on the current
         default routing domain.  Multiple ListenAddress options are
         permitted.  For more information on routing domains, see
         rdomain(4).
```

So ensure your sshd config has eg. `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 rdomain 1`. To create an instance of sshd just do:

```
# ln -s sshd /etc/rc.d/sshd_rdomainX
# rcctl enable sshd_rdomainX
# rcctl set sshd_rdomainX flags -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config-rdomainX
```

To test it try:

```
mx1#  /usr/sbin/sshd -T -f /tmp/sshd_config  | grep listenaddress
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22 rdomain 1
mx1# /usr/sbin/sshd -D -d -f /tmp/sshd_config                     
...
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-f'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='/tmp/sshd_config'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22 rdomain 1.
...
```

Comment: If your daemon won't have native rtable support, just do: `rcctl set <daemon> rtable X` and it's done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write customized(invoked via `route -T4`) ssh daemon with rc.d(8), rcctl(8), rc.subr(8).

Disable original sshd in /etc/rc.conf and put /etc/rc.d/rdomainsshd.

The template script for /etc/rc.d/rdomainssshd is:

`/usr/ports/infrastructure/templates/rc.template`

Here are OpenBSD Manual Pages:

- https://man.openbsd.org/rc.d
- https://man.openbsd.org/rc.subr.8
- https://man.openbsd.org/rcctl.8